# Error in installing Tensorflow in Python 3.9.2 with pip 21.0.1

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have installed Python 3.9.2. And mt pip version is 21.0.1.
While installing tensorflow I am getting below error
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Comment: TensorFlow is tested and supported on the following 64-bit systems: Python 3.6–3.8. Ubuntu 16.04 or later. Windows 7 or later (with C++ redistributable)

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no version of Tensorflow that would work with python 3.9.